# How to center react-select element

Tags: css, reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to put the React-select element to the center of the page. (Please Note, I'm not trying to center the text/menu but I'm trying to center the select box)

Inline Styles didn't work for me, hence I have added a div tag and was able to control the width as shown below :

```
<div style={{width: '300px'}} >
                    <Select options={selectOptions} value={selectedOption} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
</div>
```

But I'm not able to center the select element.

Any help on this ?

Comment: Adding the marginLeft fixed my issue: ````<div style={{marginLeft: "45%", width: '200px'}}>````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that could be solved easily by using a few CSS attributes.
You know, I am sure that `display: flex, justify-content: 'center', align-items: center` will work as you desire.

```
<div style={{width: '300px', display: 'flex', justify-content: 'center', align-items: 'center'}} >
                    <Select options={selectOptions} value={selectedOption} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
</div>
```